# CentOS - Remi Repo

Tags: centos, repository

I let someone try to install the latest version of PHP on my CentOS 6.5 box but they didn't succeed. They tried to install Remi Repo but that doesn't seem to be working now either.

When I'm trying to update the php I get the following error:

```
Error: Cannot find a valid baseurl for repo: rpmfusion-free
```

rpmfusion-free.repo:

```
[rpmfusion-free]
name=RPM Fusion for Fedora $releasever - Free
#baseurl=http://download1.rpmfusion.org/free/fedora/releases/$releasever/Everything/$basearch/os/
mirrorlist=http://mirrors.rpmfusion.org/mirrorlist?repo=free-fedora-$releasever&arch=$basearch
enabled=1
metadata_expire=7d
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-rpmfusion-free-fedora-$releasever-$basearch

[rpmfusion-free-debuginfo]
name=RPM Fusion for Fedora $releasever - Free - Debug
#baseurl=http://download1.rpmfusion.org/free/fedora/releases/$releasever/Everything/$basearch/debug/
mirrorlist=http://mirrors.rpmfusion.org/mirrorlist?repo=free-fedora-debug-$releasever&arch=$basearch
enabled=0
metadata_expire=7d
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-rpmfusion-free-fedora-$releasever-$basearch

[rpmfusion-free-source]
name=RPM Fusion for Fedora $releasever - Free - Source
#baseurl=http://download1.rpmfusion.org/free/fedora/releases/$releasever/Everything/source/SRPMS/
mirrorlist=http://mirrors.rpmfusion.org/mirrorlist?repo=free-fedora-source-$releasever&arch=$basearch
enabled=0
metadata_expire=7d
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-rpmfusion-free-fedora-$releasever-$basearch
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You installed the [RPM Fusion](http://rpmfusion.org/) release RPM for Fedora instead of the one for CentOS. I'm not entirely sure how you did that; it *should* reject attempts to do so.

To fix the problem, remove the release files you installed, and then [download and install the correct ones](http://rpmfusion.org/Configuration).

```
yum --disablerepo=rpmfusion-* remove rpmfusion-{,non}free-release
```

Comment: I get the following: http://pastebin.com/vjp1R8vC

Comment: OK, so edit the command line and try again.

Comment: Really appreciate your answers, and sorry for my lack of knowledge on this subject. However, it's coming out with this now: http://pastebin.com/tWXM0FuM

Comment: Bah. OK, there.